# Как реализовать метод в RX Java

Tags: android, rxjava

Только недавно начал изучать RX Java, хотелось бы понять как мне вот этот метод переписать в RX и возможно ли это?

```
@Override
    public void loadExamples(String language) {
        showProgress();
        mDatabase.collection(COLLECTION_PATH)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        List<Example> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                            Example example = document.toObject(Example.class);
                            if (example.getLanguage().equals(language)) {
                                exampleList.add(example);
                            }
                        }
                        updateUi(exampleList);
                    } else {
                        handleError(task.getException());
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Набросал вызов на Котлин, но думаю суть Вы поймете.

```
fun getData(){
    compositeDisposable?.add(Completable.fromAction{getDataTask.execute()} //Ваш метод для получения информации, нужно дерать синхронный вызов
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe { view?.showProgressBar() }
            .doFinally { view?.hideProgressBar() }
            .subscribe({
                view?.updateUi(it)
            }, { t ->
                Log.d("MainPresenter", "${t.message}")
                view?.showError()
            }))
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понял! ну т.е. я не понимаю какую часть моего метода вставлять вместо getDataTask.exute. Там же еще навешивается listener и вот оттуда мне надо как-то отселдить onComplete.